# How i can build Mupdf and use it in my Android app

Tags: android, pdf

I'm new in Android and i want to use Mupdf in my app i don't know how i can build it or implement in my app i searched a lot and didn't find any useful answer

I downloaded (mupdf-1.11-source.tar.gz) from this [link](https://mupdf.com/downloads/) and tried [this tutorial](http://mupdf.blogspot.com.eg/2013/01/compile-mu.html) but i can't build it

Please tell me how i can build it in windows and implement in my existing app

Comment: https://mupdf.com/docs/android-build-library.html

Comment: @CommonsWare i don't understand this can you explain how i can build it please

Comment: Perhaps you should search for a pre-compiled edition of MuPDF, or use some other pre-compiled library that does what you want. Otherwise, you will need to spend some time learning how to work with the Android NDK, to the point where those instructions start to make sense. Some Android books and courses cover the NDK. Also note that developing NDK code in Windows is more difficult than is working with the same code in macOS or Linux.

Comment: @a.kamal did you find any helpful tutorial or solution?